# First and last sortable items don't consistently move out of the way in jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

In a Web app I'm writing, users can add their own customized buttons to a control panel and then change the order of those buttons via drag-and-drop. I’m using jQuery UI's Sortable Widget to make the magic happen.

The buttons are arranged in a single row, left to right. I’m using flexbox to style them, and I've set the `sortable` method to allow movement only along the X axis. Everything is working well for the most part, BUT…

- Sometimes when I drag a button all the way to the beginning of
  the row, the leftmost button won’t move out of the way to make space
  for it.
- The same thing happens, sometimes, when the row has filled up with
  buttons and I try to drag a button all the way to the end of the row. (The rightmost button won't budge.)

At first, I couldn’t figure out why the buttons at the far left and right sometimes behaved as desired and sometimes didn’t. Eventually I realized it all depended on where I grabbed the button I was dragging. The JSFiddle I’ve set up illustrates the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/DanRobinson/8nap51Lg/78/

In the Fiddle, if you grab the middle button close to its left edge, you can successfully drag it to the beginning of the row, but not to the end of the row. Conversely, if you grab that same button close to its right edge, you can drag it to the end of the row, but not to the beginning.

I want the buttons to behave consistently no matter where the user happens to grab them. Is there a setting in the Sortable Widget that will solve this problem? (Changing the “tolerance” setting to “pointer” doesn’t seem to help.)

### HTML:

```html
<div id="container">        
    <div>Custom Button 1</div>
    <div>Custom Button 2 is wider than the others</div>
    <div>Custom Button 3</div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 600px;
}

#container > div {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    cursor: default;
}
```

### Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#container").sortable({
        axis: "x",
        containment: "parent",
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#container").sortable({
        axis: "x",
        containment: "parent",
        start: function(e, ui) {
            // get the instance of the sortable.
            // instance method is new to jquery ui 1.11, for previous versions
            // you can use $(this).data()['ui-sortable'];
            var sort = $(this).sortable('instance');
            // this makes the placeholder fit with the row that's being dragged
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.height());
            // containment property of the sortable instance is not the same
            // as the containment option. The property is calculated
            // from the option. You need to adjust bottom coordinates
            // to take into account the row you just removed from it and the click offset.
            sort.containment[3] += ui.helper.height() * 1.5 - sort.offset.click.top;
            // Since your handle is centered, and pointer coordinates are used
            // for sortable, but top coordinates are used for containment
            // you can have issues with top row. Adjusting with the click offset
            // will resolve the issue.
            sort.containment[1] -= sort.offset.click.top;
        },
        helper: function(e, row) {
            // From http://www.paulund.co.uk/fixed-width-sortable-tables. 
            // Sets the width of each cell to be its original width.
            // This reverts the default`enter code here` behaviour of the row collapsing into a narrower stub when being dragged.
            row.children().each(function() {
              $(this).width($(this).width());
            });
            return row;
        }
    });   
});
```

Comment: Sanjay, thanks for the nice inline comments that helped me follow what your code is doing. Unfortunately, when I put your code into the fiddle, it didn't solve the problem. (See forked version at https://jsfiddle.net/DanRobinson/8obrmkna/.)  Does your fix take into account that the items are being sorted along the x axis (left/right)? I tried changing "height" to "width" and "top" to "left" in your _start_ function, but that doesn't seem to work, either.